# Why constructor is not getting called

Tags: c++, static

In this program "A's constructor called " is printing 2 times. My doubt is why "A's constructor called " is not printing with

```
A b = B::getA();
```

while getting printed with

```
A a;
```

In both the cases we are creating a new object.

Here is my Program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl;  }
};

class B
{
    static A a;
    public:
    B() { cout << "B's constructor called " << endl; }
    static A getA() { return a; }
};

A B::a;  // definition of a

int main()
{
    A a; 
    A b = B::getA();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first constructor is called at program startup, when the static `A` within `B` is created.

The second constructor is called within your `main` when A is allocated on the stack.

There are no more calls to the default `A` constructor.  When you call `getA()` a copy constructor will be used, which as you have not defined, will be provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Because `getA()` calls a copy constructor, which you haven't written, so the default one will be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
A b = B::getA();
```

That initialises `b` using the copy constructor. You're only tracing the default constructor, which isn't used here. If you wanted to trace the copy constructor too, then you'd need to provide one:

```
A(A const &) { cout << "A's copy constructor called " << endl; }
```

Answer (score 0):

one contructore is getting called with "static A a" and "A B::a" i.e static initialization of a which is member of class B

during the execution of program in C, C++ all global and static variables initialized first.